# Call struct from map of structs

Tags: struct, go

Hi I am trying something like the following example.

My background as a PHP Developer (I know!) is giving me a hard time on this.
I've read the Laws of reflection and other sources, but this is over my head. The approach i am using is probably wrong... and hope someone can point me in the right direction.

The use of this in a concrete way is that the version 01 or 02 or 03 is comming from an external Parameter, based on that, I need to get the appropriate struct and populate it with database values.

```
package V01
type Struct1 struct{
    Field1 string
    Field2 string
}

type Struct2 struct{
    Field1 string
    Field2 string
}
```

---

```
package V02
type Struct1 struct{
    Field1 string
    Field2 string
    ExtraField1 string
}

type Struct2 struct{
    Field1 string
    Field2 string
    ExtraField2 string
    ExtraField3 string
}
```

---

```
var VStructs = map[string]map[string]interface{}{
    "01": map[string]interface{}{
        "Struct1": V01.Struct1{},
        "Struct2": V01.Struct2{},
    },
    "02": map[string]interface{}{
        "Struct1": V02.Struct1{},
        "Struct2": V02.Struct2{},
    }, 
    "03" : map[string]interface{}{
        "Struct1": V01.Struct1{},
        "Struct2": V02.Struct2{},
    }, 
}
```

---

```
 // I get the struct fieldnames and so on.
 fmt.Printf("%+v\n", VStructs["01"]["Struct1"] ) 

 // I cannot access any of the fields though because it is an interface
 fmt.Println( VStructs["01"]["Struct1"].Field1 ) // PANIC! 

 // Type Switching is not working either since the version can be variable.
 s := VStructs["01"]["Struct1"].Field1 
 switch x := s.(type) {
 case reflect.Struct: // PANIC! reflect.Struct (type reflect.Kind) is not a type
    fmt.Println("I am an struct")
 default:
    fmt.Println("I am an no struct")
 }
```

---

So maybe can show me an appropriate way of doing this. Or maybe an wrapper function to return the right struct... no clue at this point.

Hope it is clear, and will elaborate more if asked to.

Comment: You should use type names in type switch, not `reflect.Kind` values. I.e. it should be `case V01.Struct:` etc., not `case reflect.Struct:`.

Comment: @Ainar-G, thanks, but the versions V01, V02, V03 are variable, so that is not really an option specially when there are about 50 structs in each version...

Comment: Then you need to define an interface for all these structs to implement.

Comment: Could you provide me with an example the above structs could use as interface?

Comment: What you're asking right now, after an edit, is a completely different question. The original question was about maps of structs. I'd suggest asking another question, because there are way too many details to consider.

Comment: I didn't change anything particular...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, since the question was probably in conflict with the way golang is used to work.

I have written an package to serve my needs :

> Based on the selected version (In the URL or the Header, whatever you like) we retrieve an map of structs. We now can select the actual struct we need, set some values and finally send it back to the screen OR send it over to the DB (In my case gorp).

The Package can be found here https://github.com/donseba/contractor/

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access the struct inside a map this way because there may be no struct. In your example, what would `VStructs["foo"]["bar"].Field1` be? You would have no way of knowing if it's really an empty struct in the map, or there is nothing and the map access just returned you an empty value for that type. What you should do instead is an explicit check:

```
v, ok := VStructs["01"]["Struct1"]
if !ok {
    // Handle the case of the missing struct.
}
// It is also a good practice to check type assertions.
s, ok := v.(V01.Struct1)
if !ok {
    // Handle the case when v is not V01.Struct1.
}
f = s.Field1
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but with your example i get
`type interface {} has no field or method Field1`

Comment: @DonSeba I didn't notice you have an `interface{}` there. Edited the answer to reflect that.

Comment: The issue here is that "V01.Struct1" Could be "V02.Struct1" .. sorry. maybe i'm trying something to dynamic, with golang..

Comment: @DonSeba It's perfectly fine to do that in Go. In that case you either need a [type switch](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_switches) or define an interface for all these structs to implement and replace `interface{}` with this new interface type.